# C++: Quicksort words instead of numbers

Tags: c++, quicksort

I am trying to write a code that uses quicksort to sort words by alphabetical order, but when I run my code it gets stuck on inputting the user's words. What's the reason behind this? It works fine when I leave the array as an integer array. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void quicksort(char a[], int size, int left, int right)
{
    int i = left;
    int j = right;
    int pivot = a[(left+right)/2];
    char temp;
    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (a[i] < pivot) i++;
        while (a[j] > pivot) j--;
        if (i <= j)
        {
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    if (i < right)
        quicksort(a, size, i, right);
    if (j > left)
        quicksort(a, size, left, j);
}

int main()
{
    char a[10], n;
    system("clear");
    cout << "Enter the number of elements to be sorted: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter the elements to be sorted (press ENTER after each word): " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
        quicksort(a, n, 0, n-1);
        cout << endl;
    cout << "The sorted elements are: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: i think you should use 'cin.getline(a,'\n')' instead of your input for loop.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with sorting (yet). `a` is an array of characters, so `cin >> a[i]` reads a single character. But later, in the sort you do sort the characters again, not whole strings/words. I would suggest using `std::string` for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: So would I have to change the array type to `string` in order for it to sort words? Sorry, I'm fairly new to C++. @CygnusX1

Comment: std::string is an automatically managed char-array more or less, so you can treat it like a string without having to learn the ins and out of managing every individual character. char a[10] is an array of just 10 characters. you can in fact write to that by cin >> a, but that writes an unknown number of characters into the buffer "a" and can easily write past the end of the 10 memory spaces you allocated. std::string handles input size and resizing the buffer as needed, for you.

Answer (score 0):

You code may work but you're trying to read words in an array of char. You need to use a string (store a whole word) or an array of string (store multiple strings).

Your code may look like this:

```
int main()
{
    string a[10], n;
    system("clear");
    cout << "Enter the number of elements to be sorted: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter the elements to be sorted (press ENTER after each word): " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
        quicksort(a, n, 0, a[i].length -1);
    }

    cout << "The sorted elements are: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " " << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Please have in mind the that the code structure in c++ it's different than python. Have a look to this coding and naming conventions 
http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping! This is the final solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void quicksort(std::string a[], int size, int left, int right)
{
int i = left;
int j = right;
std::string pivot = a[(left+right)/2];
std::string temp;
while (i <= j)
{
    while (a[i] < pivot) i++;
    while (a[j] > pivot) j--;
    if (i <= j)
    {
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}

if (i < right)
    quicksort(a, size, i, right);
if (j > left)
    quicksort(a, size, left, j);
}

int main()
{
std::string a[100];
int n;
system("clear");
cout << "Enter the number of elements to be sorted: " << endl;
cin >> n;
cout << "Enter the elements to be sorted (press ENTER after each word): " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> a[i];
}
quicksort(a, n, 0, n-1);
cout << endl;
cout << "The sorted elements are: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << a[i] << " ";
cout << endl;

return 0;

}
```